# Read a file and Write on another

Tags: python

I made a script which reads each line of a file and I need those lines on another file but all the script does is writing only one line.
How do I make this out?

I tried to loop the read lines and each loop it would write them on the other file

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
       print line

       file = open('testfile.txt', 'w')
       file.write(line)

       if 'str' in line:
          break
```

Comment: With every loop, you are opening the file to write. I would suggest to open the file to write before the loop and execute the write statement within the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
   file = open('testfile.txt', 'w')
   for line in f:
       print line
       file.write(line)
       if 'str' in line:
          break
```

Create the text file outside of the loop will work.

Comment: @IloveCode Remember to up-vote and accept if it works, :-)

Comment: I think you should also use `with` to open the file to write. @IloveCode

Answer (score 4):

I think you should always close the file, so the file that you open to write should also use `with`

```
with open("test.txt") as f, open("testfile.txt", "w") as f2:
    for line in f:
        f2.write(line)
        if 'str' in line:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the opening line outside of the loop. When the opening line is in the loop, it creates a new file over and over, writing a single line to that file before deleting it to create a new one at the beginning of each loop iteration. When you move the opening line outside the loop, the file is only created once, writing each line to that one file instead of overwriting the whole file each time.